# Large file upload guidelines

Tags: files

I have a site built in Drupal 7.23, which is supposed to handle large files uploads to it.

I have a node form with 5 File upload fields which is supposed to take 200MB files for each.

What should be the Apache server adjustments that i need to taken in favour of making the upload process seamlessly?

Also i have Video module with FFMPEG configured to convert on cron. Someday I got message form server support team that my FFMPEG is taking 100% CPU.

Also i got some MySQL errors, like Lock TimeOut etc. what to do ?

Please let me know an optimal settings for these kind of server which runs Drupal.

Comment: taking 100% CPU - are you in shared hosting ?

Comment: @Bala nop i am in VPS ~2GB i think

Comment: I think you can do it through https://drupal.org/project/jupload , using this method (not sure) you can upload the files without issue in your server, better see this page( https://drupal.org/node/1748456 ) , it not mentioned but it processed through ftp so I think it can do the job without affecting the server.

Comment: @Bala but that will ruin my UI..

Comment: It looks like UI integration and I'm not sure, better give a try.

Comment: See the document page, It showed there with UI

Comment: You should move to Xen VPS or dedicated server to avoid resource usage warning

Comment: It looks like, you have a disk i/o problem, most probably caused by another vps that shares the disk with you. This kind of problem drove me crazy, until I moved to an ssd cloud server - more expensive but much better disk performance, thus less memory and cpu needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal for the CPU usage to be at 100% when FFMPEG runs. Video compression is a computationally difficult task.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565567/how-can-i-limit-ffmpeg-cpu-usage). If you have a two core VPS then you could make sure that FFMPEG only uses one core and thus always leaves at least one core for Apache/PHP/MySQL.

I created a similar site and it generally worked but it certainly had the occasional errors. It was a 4-core VPS and when transcoding all four cores were often at 100%. If I were to design the site again I think I would use a video transcoding service such as [Amazon's Elastic Transcoder](http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/). Making sure FFMPEG would recognize all the different file encodings especially MP4 was quite a pain.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [File Resumable Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup):

> File **Resumable Upload** aka **file_resup** adds large files multiple and
>   resumable upload to the *File* and *Image* field widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with [Remote File Source](https://drupal.org/project/remote_file_source) module without affecting locally.

> Remote File Source allows you to add a file from a remote server to a
>   filefield without transferring it locally.

Comment: I want to add files to the server and convert it into various format so that i can play it in various browsers. Also that is the requirement.